# finding code for selection

Tags: scripting

I have a great idea for a new selection tool for blender. However, for this I require the code segment that would find the objects within a particular rectangular area, e.g. when a box select border is drawn, it should identify the objects within that area and therefore goes to select them. How do I get this code segment, if it's in python it'd be great.

Comment: you can look at the source at https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/ . Selection stuff needs to be quick, so will be in C not python.

Comment: okay, not very familiar with C though.... and haven't even once looked at blender's source code... should be hard to find.